# Connect 2 server

Tags: ip, tunnel

Hi guys i need tunnel my server to another server
My country block to much website.

example
I have server from iran
And have from Germany

I need tunnel my iran server to Germany
Please i need help ❤️
Please explain with code

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. This question is not related to an Ubuntu OS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use VPN services.
Or
if you have access to a ssh server in Germany you can use this command:
ssh -L8080:blockedsite.com:80 -L8443:blockedsite.com:443 sshuser@sshserverinGermany

And in you browser access the site as:
http://localhost:8080 and
https://localhost:8443.

Look for "Local Port Forwarding using SSH"